# Prolog undefined procedure when run in file

Tags: prolog

I am getting the following error when I run this prolog code. Looking online it says this error is thrown when rules and facts are entered in at the toplevel, however I loaded these rules through a file.  What else could be causing this error?  Any help is appreciated.

ERROR: no_bad_courses/1: Undefined procedure: course_list/2

```
   no_bad_courses(Name):-
        student(Name,Id,_),
        findall(X,entry(Id,X,_),L),
        course_list(Name,L).

   course_list(Name,[Class|T]]):-
        bad_course(Name, Class), !, fail
        ;
        course_list(Name,T).
```

Comment: Is the `course_list/2` predicate defined in the file you load?

Comment: Were there any other error messages? `course_list(Name,[Class|T]])` has a syntax error (an extra `]`).